# conditional compilation in yacc

Tags: yacc

how to do conditional compilation in yacc. Similar to done in C using ifdef.
I want to create a rule based on a condition. Is it possible in yacc. Example. based on condition rule A is defined as follows:

```
ruleA : A | B, /* For condition 1 */  
ruleA : C      /* If condition 1 is not satisfied */
```

Comment: I don't recall yacc having conditional compilation "built in" (though it has been a while...). You could run your yacc file through a macro preprocessor before passing it into yacc.

Comment: We assemble some grammars from multiple component grammar fragments, and have a (home-brew) `yaccpp` to preprocess the components into the grammar submitted to Yacc.  (The full story is more convoluted than that, but it is close enough.)  You are defining your language differently depending on circumstances; that's an unusual language.

Answer (score 2):

[btyacc](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/btyacc) has conditional compilation based on defined flags, similar to the C preprocessor.  You can say:

```
%ifdef VERSION_A
ruleA: A | B ;
%endif
%ifdef VERSION_B
ruleA: C ;
%endif
```

and then use a `-DVERSION_A` or `-DVERSION_B` command line argument to get one version or the other.  Its pretty primitive (you can only test a single flag per `%ifdef`, can't nest `%ifdef`s and there's no `%else`), but its adequate for simple things.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I can't use btyacc since I require XML output (and it's not currently implemented).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't preprocess your Yacc grammar with an appropriate preprocessor, then you can use a solution based on actions:

```
ruleA : A { if  (condition1) { process OK; } else YYERROR; }
      | B { if  (condition1) { process OK; } else YYERROR; }
      | C { if (!condition1) { process OK; } else YYERROR; }
      ;
```

The YYERROR action triggers Yacc's normal error processing mechanism.  This means your grammar must 'work' with both sets of rules in operation as far as Yacc is concerned.  If this leads to complexity because of shift/reduce (or even reduce/reduce) conflicts, then preprocessing is the way to go.  The result grammar will be smaller and more focussed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I do not want to define :                                                            | C { if (!condition1) { process OK; } else YYERROR; }
in case condition is not satisfied.

Comment: I know you don't; you can't do it with pure Yacc other than as I showed.  So, get to work on your Yacc preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you expose the conditional flag as a terminal symbol, we can call it the *mode terminal.* (So, technically, it's a run-time not compile-time condition.)

You need to return the mode terminal at every point that it would make a difference in the parse. Your grammar can ignore it when it receives extra ones. It can return the mode terminal only in the "condition 1" case, only in the "not condition 1" case, or you can return a different one in both cases. So say you have two tokens C1 and C2, one for each mode.

This may not work out so well if you are parsing an existing grammar, but if you are designing the grammar and the parser together all problems are solvable.

Then you end up with:

```
ruleA : C1 A | C1 B | C2 C ;
```